# Use translations with nl2br in template

Tags: 8, views, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to use translations with `nl2br`?

I tried `{{ "This offer may \n interest you"|nl2br|t }}`, but it doesn't translate the string because it contains a `'\n'` character.

I already tried with `{% trans %}{% endtrans %}` instead of `|t`, but the result is same.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this should be a problem - `t` doesn't know/care how the string came to be. You should find the translation source under _This offer may <br /> interest you_

Comment: Do you actually want a line break to display?

Comment: The solution would surely be to include \n in the translation but I think It's not really a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `{{ "This offer may \n interest you"|nl2br|striptags|t }}`?

Comment: Yes I already tried but I still doesn't have my translation